# Adding multiple static Rust libraries in an iOS app

Tags: ios, rust, static-linking

I have two libraries (with C compatible interface) written in Rust that I'm trying to integrate into an iOS app.

When integrating the two .a files in the same project, I get errors because symbols from the Rust standard library are now present multiple times:

```
duplicate symbol _rust_eh_personality in:
    /Users/x/Development/ios-client/Y/Rust/lib1_ffi.a(lib1_ffi.0.o)
    /Users/x/Development/ios-client/Y/Rust/lib2_ffi.a(lib2_ffi.0.o)
...
```

How can this be solved? Could the Rust symbols be extracted into a separate library? Or can the symbols be namespaced?

Comment: You could try compiling both dependencies into a single .a library with just rust first, and then integrating the resulting .a into your project.

Comment: Sure, that would work in my case, but it can't be a good solution in the general case if you integrate third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this posting, the prevalent theory is that this issue occurs when Link-Time Optimization (LTO) is enabled and is caused by a bug in the static libraries that rustc produces [(link)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44322#issuecomment-330059725).

As a temporary measure, it has been suggested that LTO should not be enabled until this issue has been resolved.

Comment: *the prevalent theory*; *it has been suggested*. Does this actually work? Have you tried it?

Comment: I confirm this solved my problem. Just `lto = false` in `Cargo.toml`